# RightFax Via Application Hosted on IIS

Tags: c#, iis, rightfax

I'm having an issue getting connected to our RightFax server.  If I create a sample project in C# and use the code below I can connect just fine.  The problem is I need the same code in an application that is on my local IIS.  When it gets to OpenServer(), I get an Access Denied error.  Has anybody ever experienced this before?  Here is the very simple code I am using...

```
RFCOMAPILib.User selectedUser;
RFCOMAPILib.FaxServer fxServer; ;

fxServer = new RFCOMAPILib.FaxServer();
fxServer.ServerName = "TESTServer";
fxServer.Protocol = RFCOMAPILib.CommunicationProtocolType.cpNamedPipes;
fxServer.AuthorizationUserID = "Axxxxxx";
fxServer.AuthorizationUserPassword = "";
fxServer.UseNTAuthentication = RFCOMAPILib.BoolType.False;

fxServer.OpenServer();
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by making the process run as a domain authenticated user. Change the user that the application pool is running as and I'm sure you'll have different results.